# Not able to export report in xlxs format

Tags: apex, schedule

Is there any workaround to send out scheduled reports as Excel attachment than actually embedding it within an email?

by follow the below link i got to some point but not able to see attachment in xls format .

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008n0zIAA

Here is my code :

```
global class Exporter implements System.Schedulable {
  global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    ApexPages.PageReference report = new        
    ApexPages.PageReference('/00O90000008lrLi?xls=1&exp=1');
    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    attachment.setFileName('report.xls');
    attachment.setBody(report.getContent());
    attachment.setContentType('application/x-excel');//application/vnd.ms-excel#report.xls 
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    message.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {  attachment } );
    message.setSubject('Report');
    message.setPlainTextBody('The report is attached.');
    message.setToAddresses( new String[] { 'xx@xx.com' } );
    Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { message } );

  }
}
```

Please suggest some workaround!!!!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some error information about whats actually going wrong. Also, things to note: make sure your report has the right export settings, and the .xls file that is exported from a report is actually a html page, for some reason. Both of these could be stopping your file from working properly.

Comment: Thanx for reply!! 
When I export a report from Salesforce in .xls format and open it in Excel 2013, I always get the message:

"The file format and extension of 'reportxxxxxx.xls' don't match. The File could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you wan't to open it anyway?"

The data appears fine once you click "Yes"...I've read about something similar reported with Excel 2007